# List filter based on date

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, filtering

I have such a situation. I have a list inside which I am holding strings with date and time in such a format: `05-04-2011 12:42:03.199`. I would like to be able to filter this list accoding to date selected in datetimepicker and my custom timepicker. I am saving both values into string `string try1 = timePicker1.Value.ToString();` and `string try2 = dateTimePicker5.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`. I already done filtering with `view` like this:

```
view2.RowFilter = "TimeColumn >= '" 
                  + dateTimePicker5.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " " 
                  + try1 
                  + "' and TimeColumn <= '" 
                  + dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " " 
                  + try2 + "'";
```

I would like to know how can I do it with linq and save result to new list? Is it possible to filter it with the reduction from the top and bottom?

Hope I made it pretty clear. Is not just tell me and I will try to explaing more!

Comment: Why do you store a `DateTime` as `String`? And why do you have a `List<String>` which contains dates?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think this is more important than his filtering problem..

Comment: I do it like this, because my primary line, doesn't only consist of this data. I am first dividing it into 3 part and saving into string array. It has data and a lot of text inside. How can I do it in different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you store a `DateTime` as `String`? And why do you have a `List<String>` which contains `DateTime`s?  You should always use the most appropriate datatype and convert it to string very last.

However, this should work:

```
string dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
IEnumerable<string> filtered = strings
    .Select(str => new { str, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
    .Where(x => x.dt >= start && x.dt <= end)
    .OrderBy(x => x.dt) // if you want to order by the datetime value
    .Select(x => x.str);
```

This query takes every string and uses `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert it to a `DateTime`. Then it creates an anonymous type(`new{ .... }`) with two properties, the original `string` and the `DateTime` and filters with `Enumerable.Where` by the `DateTime` property and your start- and end-values. The remaing items are ordered by the datetime(bonus). Finally the string is selected since i've assumed that this is your desired result.

If you need to materialize the query you can use `ToList` or a simple `foreach`.

```
foreach(string strDate in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine( strDate );
}
```

**Edit** according to your comment:

> Ok, so how can I save it as Datetime when my primary line looks like
>   this 05-04-2011 12:42:04.160,Event dssd(23).dfgg[2] 1 xx:3332,some
>   more text. I am separating this lines like this and saving each part
>   into string array string[] _columns = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());.
>   How can I save first part as datetime and rest as string?

```
string dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
string[] lines = new[]{"05-04-2011 12:42:04.160,Event dssd(23).dfgg[2] 1 xx:3332,some more text"};
var lineIfos = lines.Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .Select(split => new{ 
        date = DateTime.ParseExact(split[0].Trim(), dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        rest = string.Join(",", split.Skip(1))
    })
    .Where(x => x.date >= start && x.date <= end)
    .OrderBy(x => x.date);

foreach (var x in lineIfos)
    Console.WriteLine("date:{0}  rest of the line:{1}"
        ,x.date.ToString("d")
        ,x.rest);
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit, I do not really understand it. Sorry.

Comment: I did it this way, but I still get error, here is my code:

'IEnumerable<string> filtered = list3.Select(str => new { str.LeftColumn, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }).Where(x => x.dt >= time1 && x.dt <= time2).OrderBy(x => x.dt).Select(x => x.str);'

Comment: So `LeftColum` is a property in a custom type that is the string which is actually a `DateTime`-string? You have to specify the name of the property in the anonymous type or store the variable itself, i rename it since its not a string but an object. `list3.Select(obj => new { obj, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }).Where....Select(x => x.obj)`

Comment: I corrected it, but still there is a problem that my values from datetimepicker and this try values from timepicker are strings, and when I try to parse it I get error that it is not a proper format...

Comment: I have checked it with your example string and it worked. So you need to provide a complete list of possible datetime-string(you see that it is better to use `DateTime`s, it's more efficient and less error-prone). If a string cant be converted you might want to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead to exclude invalid strings.

Comment: Ok, so how can I save it as Datetime when my primary line looks like this `05-04-2011 12:42:04.160,Event dssd(23).dfgg[2] 1 xx:3332,some more text`. I am separating this lines like this and saving each part into string array `string[] _columns = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());`. How can I save first part as datetime and rest as string?

Comment: @user2592968: Edited my anaswer accordingly. I have select the anonymous type since i don't know what your desired result is. I have added the `foreach` to show how you access the properties.